# Perform Action At DatePicker Time

Tags: ios, datepicker, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I need to send a text message when the current time equals the time selected in the UIDatePicker. How might I do this? You don't need to include the code to send the message, I already have that coded. I've tried all sorts of things with NSTimer and if - then statements but none have worked.

Edit: Since I wrote this question I've found a better way to do things. I just need to set a local notification and when received execute my code with -(void)didRevieveLocalNotification. Here is what I have so that any googlers can hopefully be helped.

```
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];
    //Set Local Notification
    UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notif.fireDate = pickerDate;
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    notif.alertBody = @"Tap to send your text message!";
    notif.alertAction = @"send message...";
    notif.soundName = @"sms_alert_nova.caf";
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

Comment: Show how you have tried using `NSTimer` and tell us what it did that was different to what you expected.

Comment: Did you try the initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: method of NSTimer?

Comment: I've unfortunately deleted all of the code that I used previously. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i would use a local notification... something like this

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = theDate //The date that your picker has selected

notification.alertBody = @"Hey, the time just expired!"
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

Then in your AppDelegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

//Code to manage the notification logic


}
```

Hope this helps, the user will get the alert even if on background.. if on background the user must click the alert to let your application know that the local notification triggered, if he does (or he is on your app already, then the app delegate method will trigger letting your app know that the notification fired...

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've done that but I would like to execute the action automatically once the user opens the app. That is why I want to detect the time and match it up. :)

Comment: explain a little please? you need the app to perform the action once the timer reach that ??? if that's the case... you can still use  this method and.. if the app was halted (shut down) you use didFinishLaunching:withOptions to detect if it was open using the notification or you can re check the timer each time the app goes to foreground (in case the user did not saw the alert)... is this what you want? if not explain so i can help you

Comment: Yes that is what I need it to do.

Comment: My only problem is that I've tried the didRecieveLocalNotification and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: you have basically two options... use a notification so internally the app can fire the notification and process it (if the app is on background the user must press the notification) if the user does not press you can always use code on didBecomeActive or didEnterForeground to detect that... on the other hand you can make your app use background processing via plist so the NSTimer can fire even on backgorund (you have to explain to apple this so they let your app et through the app store)... if this is the answer.. i'll edit and you mark it :)

Comment: didReceiveLocalNotification will trigger automatically if app is on foreground, must click it if it's on background... can you post relevant code to know why it doesn't work?

Comment: Heavy_Bullets answered my problem. I wanted the app to automatically execute the action once it is opened but if the app is in the background and then opened you have to manually do it. That answered it. Thanks.

Comment: if that answered your question, mark it as such so other people can look up the solution!!! thanks! (that also helps me =) )